# SQL how do i loop through my list of views

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, view

**Question**
How do i loop though my list of views in my SQL DB?

**background and things tried**
I have googled around for about 2 hours now and i have found quite a few ways to loop through different attributes of my DB. I can  loop through a list of tables and a list of columns and a list of counts but i have yet to find anything that allows me to loop through a list of Views.

**code to loop through tables i tried to modify**

[link i used to obtain sample code below](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1905/iterate-through-sql-server-database-objects-without-cursors/)

```
--List all the tables of current database and total no rows in it
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'' as TableName, COUNT(1) 
as TotalRows FROM ? WITH(NOLOCK)' 

--List all the tables of current database and space used by it EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?];'; 
GO
```

**sudo code for what i want to do**

```
loop through each view in list
run query here for each view
output results
```

**request for help**

Can anyone link me to more information about how to do this or provide some sample code? All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "loop through views"?  Are you trying to loop through the records in a view, or trying to loop through the list of views in your DB?

Comment: loop through my list of views. I will update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, cursors,  manual loops.  There are likely ways to find what you want (meaning the answer to your mystery query) in a set based way.  Either way, as phrased you'll need dynamic sql.

**Option 1 - a so/so method**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Views as TABLE (Object_id int, name nvarchar(200));

INSERT INTO @Views (Object_ID, name)
SELECT      Object_ID, name 
FROM        sys.views


DECLARE @viewName   nvarchar(200) = (select top 1 name from @Views);
DECLARE @sql        nvarchar(max) = '';

WHILE(Exists(select 1 from @Views)) BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'select count(*) FROM ' + @ViewName +';'
    --exec(@sql);   --careful you're not accepting user input here!
    Print (@sql);

    DELETE FROM @Views where name = @viewName;
    SET @ViewName = (select top 1 name from @Views);
END;
```

**Option 2 - A More Resilient Method**
*While trying this out in my little test DB I realized my first solution (as well as all the others) have a potential issue.*  Views *can* become out of date --meaning underlying objects change like a column rename. All of the others solutions will throw an error and stop processing.   If you're doing large/long queries this may be undesirable.  So I added a smidge of error handling to note the error and continue on processing.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ViewCount   int                = 0;
DECLARE @Counter     int                = 0;
DECLARE @sql         nvarchar(max)    = '';
DECLARE @viewName    nvarchar(200)    = ''
DECLARE @Views    as TABLE (  rownum int identity(1,1), 
                              name nvarchar(200), 
                              Primary Key clustered  (rownum)
                            );

INSERT INTO  @Views (name)
SELECT       name 
FROM         sys.views;

SET          @ViewCount = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

WHILE(@Counter < @ViewCount) BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter+1;

    SELECT  @sql = 'select count(*) FROM ' + name +';', @viewName = name
    FROM    @Views
    WHERE    rownum = @Counter;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- exec(@sql); --careful you're not accepting user input here!
        Print (@sql);
    END TRY BEGIN CATCH
        Print ('ERROR querying view - ' + @viewname + ' // ' + ERROR_MESSAGE());
    END CATCH
END;
```

Comment: thank you. I will try this code sample out and get back to your asap.

Comment: the second method looks great. I was in the process of trying out your first but i am going to stop there and just try this second one. I will let you know how it goes in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: i have accepted your answer. Thank you very much for your input. I am working with TBs of data in each view and very much needed to figure out how to get around out of date data. The error handling works great!

Comment: amazing how TB's of data changes a DBA's perspective ;-)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using cursors. And you are definitely gonna need dynamic SQL, so first go to [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). Then, you can try the following:

```
DECLARE @View VARCHAR(200), @Query VARCHAR(MAX)


DECLARE YourView CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.views

OPEN YourView
FETCH NEXT FROM YourView INTO @View
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Query = 'SELECT '''+@View+''' ViewName, COUNT(1) Rows
                  FROM '+QUOTENAME(@View)  -- Your code here
    PRINT(@Query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM YourView INTO @View
END
CLOSE YourView
DEALLOCATE YourView
```

Comment: lamak thank you. I will try this code sample out and get back to your asap. @EBarr lol

Comment: @lamak thank you very much for that link to dynamic SQL. It is a great source of information.

Answer (score 2):

I am using ROW_NUMBER() and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to iterate through the views.

This is a quick look at the work list:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME AS ViewName
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG
            ,TABLE_SCHEMA
            ,TABLE_NAME
        )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

Here is the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoopThroughViews
AS
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)
    ,@tableCount INT
    ,@i INT = 0

SELECT @tableCount = COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

WHILE (@tableCount >= @i)
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'select * from ' + ViewName
    FROM (
        SELECT TABLE_CATALOG + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME AS ViewName
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG
                    ,TABLE_SCHEMA
                    ,TABLE_NAME
                ) AS ViewNum
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
        ) x
    WHERE @i = ViewNum

    EXEC(@sql)

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

And finally the call:

```
EXEC LoopThroughViews
```

Comment: thank you. I will try this code sample out and get back to your asap.

Comment: You're row # is smarter than my top(1) / delete.